# Bought a 230V air conditioner, but my apartment is 110V. What to do?

Tags: electrical

Is it possible to somehow connect this air conditioner?
Would I have to simply change the outlet receptacle to the one it could connect to?
Can I buy some sort of an adapter?
Is it easier to return this air conditioner and get a 110V?

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no magic doohickey to solve this problem.  Not least because it introduces a bunch of other satellite problems.

These aren't like "Windows vs Mac" 2 incompatible flavors of the same thing  240V is actually more powerful, so an A/C unit would not be made 240V unless that was necessary to power its functionality.    So a 240V A/C will probably overdraw a 15A circuit even if you used the (non-cheap) tech to convert.

The right thing is to take it back and get an appropriate A/C.   *How did the salesman not have this conversation with you and make **sure** you had 240V power available?  Don't do business with them again, they stink at their job!*

Comment: Another salesman  with Swiss Cheese knowledge (where'd I get that from).  Definitely take it back. It's not worth the effort to jury rig it and you'll probably void the warranty. +

Answer (score -5):

You can buy a device that has two 110 to one 220 plug you just have to make sure that you are plugging in to a different plug from the first outlet. They should be on opposite sides of the breaker.

Comment: Doing that is *extremely dangerous*. Except possibly for testing purposes, that should never, ever be done. Among other problems, if one breaker tripped due to an overload and the other one did not, you could end up with unexpected hot wires. When done properly, with a 240V receptacle, this is called an MWBC, and those have special requirements to keep them safe.